Realtek b851 WiFi Card doesn't work in Ubuntu
My wife recently bought a new computer (ASUS X1504VAP-NJ815W) and I tried to install Kubuntu LTS on it. Originally after installation the computer would go to a blank screen after reboots, however I fixed this fault by updating to the latest packages using a USB to Ethernet adapter. I am now trying to get the inbuilt WiFi card up and running but am running into issues. lspci reports the card as:
0000:01:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device b851

I then googled this b851 and it seems that it should be part of the rtw89 driver found here:
https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw89
So I followed the installation instructions. However, when I run "make" as recommended in the readme, I get the following error:
/home/XXXX/rtw89/core.c: In function ‘rtw89_core_register_hw’:
/home/XXXX/rtw89/core.c:4678:37:error: ‘WIPHY_FLAG_DISABLE_WEXT’ undeclared (first use in this function)
4678 | hw->wiphy->flags |= WIPHY_FLAG_DISABLE_WEXT;
| ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/XXXX/rtw89/core.c:4678:37:note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it
appears in
make[3]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:243: /home/XXXX/rtw89/core.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [/usr/src/linux-headers-6.8.0-31-generic/Makefile:1926: /home/XXXX/rtw89] Error 2
make[1]: *** [Makefile:240: __sub-make] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.8.0-31-generic'
make: *** [Makefile:104: all] Error 2

lsb_release -a reports the following Ubuntu version:
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
Release:        24.04
Codename:       noble

uname -r reports the following linux kernel:
6.8.0-31-generic

I also followed the slightly different instructions here which appears to be for a slightly different chipset version but still covered under RTW89. Unlike the readme instructions on the github page, this seems to install correctly, however the Wifi card is still not working after reboot.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Cheers.
edit: After running through some fault finding with jeremy31 on ubuntuforums.org, I've raised a bug report on Launchpad: Bug Report. Wireless Info Script output can be found here.

Not sure why you would need github as the 6.8 kernel has the driver for that wifi

It doesn't work, hence why I'm here. I've just tried it again with a fresh install of 24.04.1 and although a number of other issues I noticed are now fixed, the WiFi still doesn't work out of the box.

OK, I got it fixed but I'm not 100% sure how it was fixed. Earlier I followed your instruction (Turned it off, disconnected power, held power button for 30 seconds), turned it on and it wasn't working. I then went into the BIOS, reset to defaults and tested it but the WiFi card was still not working. Today I decided to open the laptop up to try and find the CMOS battery, but it looks like you need to disassemble about 90% of this laptop just to get to the CMOS battery (I'm assuming it's behind the motherboard like some other ASUS laptops, because it's not visible when I open the cover). I then decided to close it up without fully disassembling it and write back to you what I'd done so far, however I noticed that the WiFi was suddenly working. Thanks for your help.
